# Getting this error Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs

Trying to run this angular function, But I am getting this error Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop. What shall I do for fix

Here's my angular Service which returns an interger of year like 2020

```
  function getMaxYear() {
        var url = apiService.ApiUrl + "/Disbursements/DisbursementSchedule/Max";
        return apiService.DeferredGet(url);

    };
```

How can I change below angular function in controller to display range of dates between current year till 2020(result that we got from api ). So var range should have 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020

```
$scope.myfunction = function () {
        var range = [];
        var startYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var endYear;
        disbursementsModel.GetMaxYear().then(function (response) {

            endYear = response.data;

            return response;
        });

        while (startYear <= endYear) {
            range.push(startYear++);
        }

        return range;
    }
```

Here is my html

```
<select ng-options="year for year in myfunction()" name="year" ng-model="year" required>
    <option value selected disabled>select year</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hard to tell - what are you using for `myfunction`? that should really return the same array instance each time.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Updated question

Comment: missing the consumer to `myfunction`.

Comment: @DanielA.White updated question

Comment: don't use a `function` for that.

Comment: How can I do that then. Please help to suggest

Comment: are you using `$http`?

Comment: Yes @DanielA.White as described in question I am calling webapi using angular service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using functions for that purpose. Just assign the values to `$scope` as they come in.

Given your API is using `$http` or returns a `$q` promise:

```
$scope.years = [];

function refreshYears() {
   $scope.years.length = 0; 

   disbursementsModel.GetMaxYear().then(function (response) {
       var startYear = new Date().getFullYear();
       var endYear = response.data;

       while (startYear <= endYear) {
            $scope.years.push(startYear++);
       }
   });
}
```

Call `refreshYears` as you need to to get the new values and use `years` in your `ng-options`.

Comment: Hi Daniel I tried this its not working. Problem is its not calling RefreshYears function. Can you please help me how to use it in ng-options.

Comment: just call refreshYears after `$scope.years = []`;

Comment: I tried that too Dan. But no luck. Can you please help out

Comment: does your service return a `$q` promise?

Comment: I am using service as same defined above in my question

Comment: you'll have to edit your question and define what `apiService.DeferredGet(url);` does...

Comment: Finally fixed it Dan, Sorry, It was my mistake like I was using Capital Y in Years in ng-options. So I have changed to years in ng-options

Comment: Glad you helped me